# CKEditor5 setData() stripping <code> tags

Tags: ckeditor5

When I try to run

```
editor.setData("<p>test comment</p><code class=\"python-code\">def withCodeBlock:<br /> print('test')</code>");
```

The resulting editor contains the html:

```
<p>test comment</p>
<p>def withCodeBlock:
<br>print('test')</p>
```

It strips out the `<code>` tags, how can I stop this?

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue, my sanitizer was removing a wrapping `<pre>` tag around the codeblock

```
editor.setData("<p>test comment</p><pre><code class=\"python-code\">def withCodeBlock:<br /> print('test')</code></pre>");
```

works perfect